# Loki the villain in Avengers

Tags: marvel, avengers, marvel-cinematic-universe, loki

In the Avengers (2012), Loki is observed to not have much powers except his sceptre (known as the blue stick of destiny by Tony). We even see that in the final battle, the avengers are fighting the most with the army of Loki and least with Loki himself although Loki is the main villain. Is my understanding of Loki's powers wrong? Or what is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loki's main power is the ability to *deceive*. It's a mental power, not a physical one. And of course you can see the evidence of that power throughout the film -- how do you think he gets the Chitauri forces to fight for him?

Comment: Right, that is visible in the film. Thanks!